# Accessing Data of ViewController in its addSubview using UIHostingController

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a form that is embedded in a view controller like this:

```
    let formController = UIHostingController(rootView: PostCallForm())
    if let form = formController.view {
        form.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(form)
        self.addChild(formController)
```

The view in which it's embedded takes data via the MVC setup like so:

```
class ClientInfoController: UIViewController {

var client: Calls? {
    didSet {
        infoLabel.text = client?.callID
    }
}
```

My form is in a separate file `form.swift`:

```
struct PostCallForm: View {
  
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Toggle(isOn: $submission.fieldOne ) {
                    Text("Field One")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $submission.fieldTwo ) {
                    Text("Field Two")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $submission.fieldThree ) {
                    Text("Field Three")
                }
                
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.placeSubmission()
                    }){
                        Text("Submit")
                    }
                }

            }
                
        .alert(isPresented: $showingConfirmation) {
            Alert(title: Text("Call Submitted!"), message: Text(confirmationMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")) 
    
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to be able to access the ViewController `var client: Calls?` data in my form, so that I can reference `client.callID` in my completion handler in my form. What is the best non-hacky way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach:

```
// Introduce view model for form
class FormViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var client: Calls? = nil
}

class ClientInfoController: UIViewController {
private var formVM = FormViewModel() // create form view model 

var client: Calls? {
    didSet {
        infoLabel.text = client?.callID
        formVM.client = client            // << update !!
    }
}

...
    let formController = UIHostingController(rootView: 
         PostCallForm().environmentObject(formVM))       // << inject !!

...

struct PostCallForm: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: FormViewModel      // << use !!
  
    var body: some View {
```

Comment: Beautiful stuff.