# How do I access a @StateObject in a SwiftUI view and update it from a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following `StateObject` in my `SwiftUI` view:

```
@StateObject var state = AnnotateImageToolbarState()
```

Where `AnnotateImageToolbarState`:

```
final class AnnotateImageToolbarState: ObservableObject {

    enum Constants {
        static let defaultColor: Color = .black
    }

    @Published var selectedColor: Color? = Constants.defaultColor
    @Published var isEraserSelected = false
    @Published var isAnnotateText = false

    func resetDefaults() {
        selectedColor = Constants.defaultColor
        isEraserSelected = false
    }

}
```

I init my `SwiftUI` View in a view controller:

```
// MARK: - Views

private let toolbar = AnnotateImageToolbar()
private lazy var hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: toolbar)

// MARK: - View Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupViews()
}

// MARK: - Setup

private func setupViews() {
    view.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor

    addChild(hostingController)
    view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
    updateToolbarConstraints(isHidden: false)
}
```

I want to be able to update values in the state from the view controller, eg in my view controller:

```
private func updateToolbarType() {
    toolbar.state.isAnnotateText = true
}
```

However I get the error `Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.`

How would I go about changing the state values from the view controller?

Comment: In this case it looks more appropriate to have `state` not as internal StateObject, but as externally injected EnvironmentObject. Look here at similar situation and solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/63608740/12299030

Comment: I see it thanks. Any idea why it's not possible to init via lazy? `private lazy var toolbarHostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: AnnotateImageToolbar().environmentObject(toolbarState))` gives the error `Property definition has inferred type 'UIHostingController<some View>', involving the 'some' return type of another declaration` in my view controller

Comment: But if I create it in `viewDidLoad` there isn't an issue....